# Bean e Annotations com Genéricos, como fazer?

Tags: java, spring

Estou num projeto com Spring 4 configurando o Redis e surgiu uma construção assim:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.empresa.sistema.web.util"})
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas agora queria fazer algo assim:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, T> template = new RedisTemplate<String, T>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resposta: não tem como fazer sem oferecer um tipo à instância. O que pode ser feito é algo assim:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, MeuObjeto> redisTemplateMeuObjeto() {
    RedisTemplate<String, MeuObjeto> template = new RedisTemplate<String, MeuObjeto>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}
```

Antes do Spring 4, é preciso usar [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html):

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("redisTemplateMeuObjeto")
private RedisTemplate<String, MeuObjeto> customRedisTemplate;
```

Spring versões 4 em diante, pode-se usar apenas o `@Autowired`, pois com o recurso da classe [`ResolvableType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html), a inferência é automática:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, MeuObjeto> customRedisTemplate;
```